# How to add a list under a dictionary?

Tags: python

I have as input a csv file of the following format:

```
#date,time,process(id),thread(id),cpuusage
201412120327,03:27,process1(10),thread1(12),10
201412120327,03:27,process2(11),thread1(13),10
201412120328,03:28,process1(10),thread2(12),10
201412120328,03:28,process2(10),thread2(13),10
```

I'm trying to create a data structure where I can use the process id as an has key for all the entries of csv that match it. See the code below.

```
# open the file
f = open (cvs_file)
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

# List of processes, with all the repetitions
processes = []
# Dictionary for the threads
threads = {}
for row in csv_f :
    # Populate already the list of processes
    processes.append(row[2])
    threads[row[2]] = row
```

My problem is that using this I don't get a list of rows under the key, but only the last value I put there. Which is sort of logical, if I thik about it. How can I add a list of (lists) rows, which is what I intended ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to create an empty list if the key isn't there yet, and append your rows to the list (freshly created or not):

```
threads = {}
for row in csv_f:
    # Populate already the list of processes
    processes.append(row[2])
    threads.setdefault(row[2], []).append(row)
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: for this usecase `dict.setdefault` is just.. simpler. It's right there on the default type, doesn't require an import and doesn't require explaining how to convert back to a regular dictionary (or why it shouldn't matter).